# list of viewmodel found empty when calling from different class in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I don't understand why this is happen when I am calling the `this3()` of same class this works fine but when calling data method `Myclass.this2()` of different class , it found empty

Please see below example when call method `this2()` from `Myclass` `TaskList`found Empty

```
TaskList =Myclass.This2();
```

and when I am using method of same class it showing proper data

```
this3();
```

Code:

```
  class MyClass
  {             
      static  public RootObject  this2()
      {
          RootObject _obj = new RootObject(); 
          _obj.TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
          _obj. TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
           _obj.TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
         return _obj;
      }    
  }      
  public async void http()
  {
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
       var data = await client.GetStringAsync("http://Examplea&employeeId=627&userId=578");
       RootObject _RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
       TaskList= MyClass.this2().TaskList;  // not works
       this3();                         //this working fine              
  }

  public void this3()
  {
      TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
      TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
      TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
 }
```

now find the complete classes code   below
please find below the complete code. there are two classes  1 is RootObject  that is my viewmodel class and TaskList is ObservableCollection of RootObject Class . when i am add the data in TaskList from other Class (MyClass.This2()) it doesnot show the data on the grid but it shows count it debug point

```
 class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

          static  public RootObject  this2()
          {

              RootObject _obj = new RootObject();
              new RootObject();
           _obj.TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "rehan", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
           _obj. TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "123641", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
           _obj.TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "123654478", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
           return _obj;
          }


    }

    public class RootObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Result result { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string loccheckincom { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Taskarray> TaskList { get; set; }
        public RootObject()
        {
            TaskList = new ObservableCollection<Taskarray>();
            // dataload();
        }
        public bool IsDataLoaded
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


        public async void http()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var data = await client.GetStringAsync("http://Example ?z=Asia/Kolkata&emplemoyeeId=627&userId=578");
            RootObject _RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
            this2();
            this.TaskList = new ObservableCollection<Taskarray>(MyClass.this2().TaskList);

        }

        public void this2()
        {
            TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
            TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
            TaskList.Add(new Taskarray() { id = 10, title = "asdfdsfdsaf", clientname = "dasfadsFadsF" });
        }




        public async void LoadHttp()
        {
            try
            {
                Formating _obj = new Formating();
                RootObject rootobject= await _obj.loaddata();
                TaskList = rootobject.TaskList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
        {
            var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp / 1000).ToLocalTime();
        }

        private string getstatus(int s)
        {
            string ret = "";

            switch (s)
            {

                case 0:
                    ret = "Pending";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ret = "New";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ret = "Completed";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    ret = "Checked In";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return ret;

        }

        private string getimage(int p)
        {
            string ret = "";

            switch (p)
            {

                case 0:
                    ret = "/Assets/priority_high.png";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ret = "/Assets/priority_medium.png";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ret = "/Assets/priority_low.png";
                    break;              
                  default:
                    break;
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose TaskList is an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the class you defined the TaskList property on, and raise the PropertyChanged event when you change the value of the property

Comment: Thanks.. i do that but giving same result

Comment: Could you please add the code for how you: 1) bind to the `TaskList` 2) the code for the property `TaskList`? Please try to make the code a bit more readable (formatted properly) when you add it so that we can more easily understand your code.

Comment: You didn't add the necessary code. You'll need to use  `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `TaskList`. Could you please show that code? Like in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged

Comment: thanks...... please the complete code. there are two classes  1 is RootObject  that is my viewmodel class and TaskList is ObservableCollection of RootObject Class . when i am add the data in TaskList from other Class (MyClass.This2()) it doesnot show the data on the grid but it shows count it debug point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the TaskList property with notification and use full property

Instead of

```
public ObservableCollection<Taskarray> TaskList { get; set; }
```

Use this

```
    private ObservableCollection<Taskarray> _TaskList;
    public ObservableCollection<Taskarray> TaskList
    {
        get { return _TaskList; }
        set
        {
            _TaskList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TaskList");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `async void`. Change all your `async void` methods to `async Task` methods and `await` the returned task.

E.g., change

```
http();
this3();
```

to

```
await httpAsync();
this3();
```

Comment: But, that doesn't actually do anything in the code. The `TaskList` property is set to an instance of a new instance of the `RootObject` that doesn't use the result of the `GetStringAsync` call at all.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, are you sure it does not? The code is messy. For example, `http()` is not getting called anywhere in his code. Why is it there at all?

Comment: The `this2` function (sigh!) is there, and it creates a new `RootObject` which then assigns a `TaskList`, which then is all returned, and only `TaskList` is used and set into the `TaskList` property. It's less than stellar code/style/naming.